# get three values from special charachter python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string as shown "--f=tt --i=3 --s=0" and I want to grab each value indiviualy. I tried :

```
command ="--f=tt --i=3 --s=0"
value1 = command.split("--f=",1)[1]
value2 = command.split("--i=",1)[1]
value3 = command.split("--s=",1)[1]
print value1 
print value2
print value3
```

something is wrong. Any help would be good. thanks

Comment: It won't work because when you do command.split("--f=",1) it splits the string by every occurrence of "--f=", so you will get a list ['','tt --i=3 --s=0'].

Comment: Why don't you just use argparse (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) that is way simpler then doing it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use module `re`:

```
import re
command ="--f=tt --i=3 --s=0"
re.findall("--\w+=(\w+)", command)
>>> ['tt', '3', '0']
```

you can use map and lambda:

```
map(lambda x:x.split("=")[-1], command.split())
>>> ['tt', '3', '0']
```

May be you better look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)